# How to create an overlay view within an activity

Tags: android

I have a requirement where i have an activity which shows list of items like facebook feeds and when clicking on a button from one of the list item a dialog has to popup which will show comments for that item.

I was going through the documentation and found out that we have to create a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) on the fly to achieve this. Please advice if this is the right approach.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't actually have to use a Dialog. I think dialogs are more appropriate when you want to show simple views or just an alert/confirmation to the user (normally done with an AlertDialog).

For your situation I guess the best approach would be to have a FrameLayout on your Activity, sibling of your main layout element, and add a Fragment to it when you want to show a popup like that over your main Activity's layout. As long as you put the fragment's view after your activity's root layout element, the fragment will be displayed on top of your main layout, as an overlay. e.g.:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Activity's main layout here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/overlay_fragment_container"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</merge>
```

and then on your Activity when you want to display the fragment you do:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.overlay_fragment_container, yourFragment)
        .commit();
```

Hope it helps :) Luck!

Comment: Also, you might want to check whether you already have this fragment loaded. Example on http://android.codota.com/scenarios/51891625da0a971a9b2a708a/android.app.FragmentManager?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34

Comment: Victor, Can you explain why you have suggested to use </merge> tag? Can we have a normal layout as parent and within that we can have a FrameLayout? Also should i use a FragmentActivity when you have a fragment inside an activity?

Comment: The root view from activities (the view with id android.R.id.content, where the layout you load is set) is a FrameLayout. Instead of using the merge tag I could use a FrameLayout as the root of my file, but then I would just complicate the view hierarchy further needlessly, since a FrameLayout with match_parent width/height inside a FrameLayout is just an useless redundancy. You can just interpret the merge tag as a FrameLayout anyway.

Comment: If you are developing with a minimum SDK higher than 11 (gingerbread) you can just use a normal Activity, though if you want to target lower platforms and still use fragments, you should include the support package on your project and use FragmentActivity instead.