# How do I create a popup overlay view in an activity without Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, overlay

I'd like to show a popup onto my `Activity` when a button is pressed. I was inspired [by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19342255/3866010).

So I use the "merge" control in the content xml of the activity and put in it the 2 different Layouts, the problem occurs obviously at this line (code taken from the question linked above):

```java
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.overlay_fragment_container, yourFragment)
    .commit();
```

because of course, `FragmentManager` works for `Fragments`.

My issue is that my `Activity` is not "fragmented". The `LinearLayout` is inflated directly in the `Activity`, not in a `Fragment` within the `Activity`.

Can I get a similar effect like that question in an `Activity` or shall I forcibly embed all its controls in a `Fragment`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [DialogFragment's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: Should I use it also if my view shoudln't be just a multiple button ask choice? I need a rate view with a RatingBar and an EditText to pick the comment. Would DialogFragment be good for it? (Maybe yes because I'm gonna add still 2 buttons too to either rate or cancel)

Comment: Yeah, [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) is the standard dialog for confirmation etc, but `DialogFragment` is much more flexible (which you need).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so this might seem like a lot of code, but it's really easy.

First, you will create the dialog layout you want in XML.  (not in the same XML as the activity view) Here's an example.

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/btnBtmLeft"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/btnBtmRight"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your **Activity** do the following:

```
private void showMyDialog(Context context) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Button btnBtmLeft = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnBtmLeft);
    Button btnBtmRight = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnBtmRight);

    btnBtmLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnBtmRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do whatever you want here
        }
    });

    /**
     * if you want the dialog to be specific size, do the following
     * this will cover 85% of the screen (85% width and 85% height)
     */
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dialogWidth = (int)(displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85);
    int dialogHeight = (int)(displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.85);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);

    dialog.show();
}
```

And finally, in onCreate of your activity, call that method

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showMyDialog(context);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!